# Bootstrap Nav bar css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Im having trouble getting my page aligned properly. It seems no matter what i do none of the rows align the way i would like them to. either the images are off misaligned from the main img or captions below those images don't line up properly.

I would like the arrows to line up at the same level as the services/faq/contact and the paragraphs below those to be aligned to the left. But it seems i cant achieve this without playing with margins in 10 different places.

http://www.bootply.com/bilUlNXdnE

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOHpT.jpg

Comment: Please post proper jsFiddle or demo site so that we can take a look.. We can't do anything just by looking at the image :-(

Comment: Thanks for your Bootply, but it's totally broken (missing a lot a HTML)

Comment: @RahulPatil sorry about that i have edited the original post http://www.bootply.com/bilUlNXdnE

Comment: @nevermind I told a friend who is a web developer i wanted to learn to build websites. He said to learn bootstrap. Not for a client or school assignment. Just trying to figure all of this out.

Comment: @Chris, i think that you should start with basic html/css/js first, then bootstrap. They say - that bootstrap (or any css framework) will make work faster and easier, but, sometimes it makes more problems, than it solves (imho).

Comment: @nevermind Already on it! I have been taking courses on [treehouse](http://www.teamtreehouse.com) for a few weeks now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is not just an answer but I just want to guide you through the right direction..

I see you created separate div for Headers, arrows and descriptions. I don't think that is the right way to do it. Rather, you can make one div for columns (including header, image, arrows and description)..

Your Code :

```
<div class="row " id="icons">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <img src="img/bottle.gif" class="image-responsive " id="spray" width="300" alt="" height="240">      
  </div><!--/#Spray-->   

  <div class="col-md-4">
    <img src="img/vacuum.gif" class="image-responsive " id="vacuum" width="300" alt="" height="240">      
  </div><!--/#Vacuum--> 

  <div class="col-md-4">
    <img src="img/mop.gif" class="image-responsive " id="mop" alt="" width="300" height="240">      
  </div><!--/#Mop-->
</div>


<div class="row" id="captions">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <h3>Services</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <h3>FAQ</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <h3>Contact</h3>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="row" id="arrows">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <img src="img/arrow8.gif" class="image-responsive" id="arrow1" alt="" width="18" height="18">      
   </div>

  <div class="col-md-4">
    <img src="img/arrow8.gif" class="image-responsive" id="arrow2" alt="" width="18" height="18">
   </div>

  <div class="col-md-4">
    <img src="img/arrow8.gif" class="image-responsive" id="arrow3" alt="" width="18" height="18">
  </div>
</div>


<div class="row" id="blurbs">
  <div class="col-md-4" id="blurb1">      
    <div class="services"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</p></div>
  </div><!--/#Spray-->   

  <div class="col-md-4" id="blurb2">      
    <div class="FAQ"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</p></div>
  </div><!--/#Vacuum--> 

  <div class="col-md-4" id="blurb3">      
    <div class="contact"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</p></div>
  </div><!--/#Mop--> 
</div>
```

This is a loose coupling between elements that are in same context (e.g. Header, Image, description etc.).

I would recommend you to code something like this -

```
<div class="col-md-4">
   <img src="img/bottle.gif" class="image-responsive " id="spray" width="300" alt="" height="240"> 
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8">
         <h3>FAQ</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4"><img src="img/arrow8.gif" class="image-responsive" id="arrow1" alt="" width="18" height="18">  </div>
   </div>
   <div class="services">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</p>
   </div>
</div>
<!--/#Column1-->   


<div class="col-md-4">
   <img src="img/vacuum.gif" class="image-responsive " id="spray" width="300" alt="" height="240"> 
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8">
         <h3>FAQ</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4"><img src="img/arrow8.gif" class="image-responsive" id="arrow1" alt="" width="18" height="18">  </div>
   </div>
   <div class="FAQ">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</p>
   </div>
</div>
<!--/#Column2-->  


<div class="col-md-4">
   <img src="img/mop.gif" class="image-responsive " id="spray" width="300" alt="" height="240"> 
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8">
         <h3>FAQ</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4"><img src="img/arrow8.gif" class="image-responsive" id="arrow1" alt="" width="18" height="18">  </div>
   </div>
   <div class="contact">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</p>
   </div>
</div>
<!--/#Column3-->
```

This way, you don't have to play much with margin and stuff..

Edited example : http://www.bootply.com/ZnylDYHd6x

Comment: Thank you! This seems much more intuitive than what i was trying.